# Send output of cron runs to an external e-mail address from EC2 instance

Tags: unix, amazon-ec2, cron, exim

What I want to do is pretty simple - I want the output from cron on an EC2 instance to go to an external e-mail address.  I've clearly done some wrong things, though, and am confused.

I've configured exim4 to use gmail as a smart host, but somehow I've managed to do something to get the e-mails from the cron daemon to come as `From: Cron Daemon <email address from /etc/exim4/passwd.client>`.  Why has cron decided to run as me?

I have

```
root: external@email.com
user-account: external@email.com
```

in /etc/aliases.  However, I get emails sent to  that say

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
root@domu-____.compute-1.internal
```

Why is exim4 trying to reach root by such a weird-looking e-mail address?  I could theoretically add domu-(redacted).compute-1.internal as a local domain in the exim4 config, but these are dynamically provisioned instances, and that would be a real pain, and I also don't know where in the world that domain is coming from - hostname -f gives ip-11-11-11-11.ec2.internal.  What have I done to make cron do something other than just send to root@localhost (which given my config would work fine)?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the fallowing line on your cron file:

mailto="external@email.com"

if three are delivery errors please paste them here

Comment: Hm, I'll try that next time I set this up - the machines I was working on this problem on have long since been decommissioned.